# Why is GIF not animating by itself?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple .gif image on my web page. In JavaScript I have:

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

I am using Glassfish Server and basically, the process takes a little long even though I have submitted the form as soon as it loads. Thus, the control remains on the page for 2-3 seconds before it is redirected to some other page (as the process is a little complex). My problem is, even though the control remains on the same page why is the .gif not animating?

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: AS I know, gif image should animate by browser, regardless of DOM and JavaScript environment. I wonder if the problem is not caused by server or JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the form is submitted, the animation of the gif stops (which is immediate since you submit `onload`). This is because the HTTP request is being made. To allow the gif to animate there are a few options:

1. Use AJAX to submit the form.
2. Use an iframe - either to submit the form or easier - to load the gif.
3. Try a few other tricks such as not submitting the form immediately.

```js
window.onload = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }, 1000);
};
```

In this example, if my theory is correct, at least for 1 second, you will see the gif animating.

Comment: For my example, adding a gif into an iframe did not allow it to continue its animation when Javascript is working.